# Are Jewish adjudication DAOs Jewish?

Tags: choshen-mishpat-civil-law, beit-din-court

Is a majority Jewish owned [arbitration market](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/arbitration.asp#:%7E:text=Arbitration%20is%20a%20mechanism%20for,decisions%20are%20final%20and%20binding.)/adjudication [DAO](https://www.investopedia.com/tech/what-dao/) considered to be a Jewish court? What about a 100% Jewish-owned arbitration market? Does it matter if the market is "mishpat Ivri" paradigm?

What % of dayyanim have classical semichah anyway?

Comment: What is an "arbitration market/adjudication DAO"? What do you mean by "classical semichah"?

Comment: @JoelK - I linked the terms to relevant online definitions

Comment: Please describe essential aspects of the entities you're asking about in the question post. The second paragraph could be posted as a separate question (with more explanation of what you mean by "classical semichah), and should be edited out here.

Comment: If they don't have classical semichah aren't they just a hebrew-style arbitration market?

Comment: That question was direct at you @IsaacMoses

Comment: @הראל Please clarify and narrow this post in the ways I've suggested, and I'll reopen it. Note that question posts are for requests for information, not for opening debates.

Comment: Why are you parsing the last question as the opening of a debate rather than a question @IsaacMoses. It's obviously a question.

Comment: הראל, I don't understand why you would direct any question at all about this topic at me. If you want information about the statistical reality of contemporary Beit Din composition, please post that as its own question post. Tacked on to this question about DAO batei din, it reads as either a separate question or a rhetorical question intended to advance an argument rather than to request information. The latter sense is compounded by your question to me in the comments. If you want to get this post reopened, [edit]s may do the trick; comments won't.